# In XPages Mobile App / Mobile Control, how to make picklist

Tags: xpages, mobile-controls

I have two pages, one page for input, another page for the options, how to send value form page to another page on xPages Mobile Controls, or is there another way to make like this.

See my sample page:
1. Page 1:User Input

http://i1248.photobucket.com/albums/hh490/dannysumarnach/page_1_form_user_input.jpg

1. Page 2:Picklist

http://i1248.photobucket.com/albums/hh490/dannysumarnach/page_2_user_choice_PickList.jpg

note: the built-in typeahead not posible

Regards,

Danny

Answer (score 0):

The in built type ahead is missing the dojo tundra.css file when using the single page app control. This file comes with Dojo its just not being included. Import this file to get the type ahead to work.

I'm unsure as to what you mean about passing value from one page to another, you can submit data to a document and open it in another page, add it to a scoped variable, add a parameter to the URL. All of these options will work.

Comment: I mean, on the sample picture, when users want to fill field MyTask on Page 1:Form, then Page2:Pick List displayed, user click/select on of Task from Page2:PickList, then back to Page1:Form, value from selected task, add/insert to field MyTask, and so on.

Comment: Sounds like the data should be written to a domino doc and then open the data in the day view control. Have a look at the discussion and Teamroom templates that come with the ExtLib. Click all documents on either and you are presented with a list of domino docs.

Comment: if either my answer or pauls above helped you, please mark one as top answer so other developers will know what to do if they face the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my blog post on this topic. There are a couple of gotchas to get around, most notably, ensuring the the page with your document datasource gets recalculated at the correct time. I'm working on a NotesIn9 on it.

Part 3 covers a couple of amendments to get it working with existing documents and includes a sample page that will work in the Extension Library Demo db. Note the extra view that needs to be created and other details in Part Two.
http://www.intec.co.uk/xpages-mobile-controls-and-value-pickers-part-three-client-side-approach-extended/